# Http GET Request Android

Tags: android, web-services, http, rest

I know that it's possible to put some data in `GET` `request body`, but I know that it's not a good practice.

Though I want to do it but i don't know how. I searched the web but couldn't find anything.

Can you give me some little code examples or reference me to some usefull info.

Let's say we have this code, how to add `nameValuePairs` to `request body` of `GET request` :

```
        String url = "something";
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(),
                TIMEOUT_MS);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), TIMEOUT_MS);
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dtype", "0"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category_id", ""));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        System.out.println("log in");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to use HttpPost class rather HttpGet

Comment: I know but right now I want to use GET.